# articulate storyline ajax error

Tags: jquery, articulate-storyline

I have a simple storyline slide with one variable on it , and I run this javascript when timeline starts.

Here is my code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "****",
    type: "GET",    
    success: function (data) {  
    alert(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {    
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    });
```

The url is correct , I have tested it in the browser. 
I do publish, with WEB option.
This is the error I get :
{"readyState":4,"status":404,"statusText":"error"}

The url is a php page with this content:

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
?>
```

This is the content of the generated html page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!-- Created using Storyline 360 - http://www.articulate.com  -->
  <!-- version: 3.16.15842.0 -->
  <title>Untitled1</title>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

  <style rel="stylesheet" data-noprefix>.slide-loader{position:absolute;pointer-events:none;left:50%;top:50%;-webkit-animation:spin 1.8s linear infinite;-moz-animation:spin 1.8s linear infinite;-ms-animation:spin 1.8s linear infinite;animation:spin 1.8s linear infinite;width:100px;height:100px;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);z-index:10000;background:transparent url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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") no-repeat center center}.mobile-chrome-warning{position:fixed;width:300px;height:75px;bottom:0px;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.0001);display:none;pointer-events:none;z-index:99}.mobile-chrome-warning-btn{position:absolute;left:-16px;top:-15px;width:107px;height:107px;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);border-radius:50%;border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);pointer-events:all;-webkit-transform:scale(0.6)}.mobile-chrome-warning-btn svg{position:absolute;left:60%;top:58%;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%)}.mobile-chrome-warning-bubble{position:relative;color:white;padding:10px;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);border-radius:5px;float:left;margin-left:100px;margin-top:15px;pointer-events:none}.mobile-chrome-warning-bubble:before{position:absolute;top:8.5px;left:-20px;width:30px;height:30px;content:'';display:block;width:0;height:0;border-style:solid;border-width:12.5px 20px 12.5px 0;border-color:transparent rgba(0,0,0,0.8) transparent transparent;pointer-events:none}.is-mobile .swipe-resume-arrow{position:fixed;top:30%;left:50%;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, 0);width:12%}.is-mobile .mobile-chrome-warning-text{position:fixed;top:56%;left:50%;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, 0);height:30%;width:80%;line-height:43px;text-align:center;color:#aeb7bd;word-break:break-word;font-size:20px}.slide-loader .mobile-loader-dot{display:none}@-ms-keyframes spin{from{-ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg)}to{-ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg)}}@-moz-keyframes spin{from{-moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg)}to{-moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg)}}@-webkit-keyframes spin{from{-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg)}to{-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes spin{from{transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg)}to{transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg)}}body.is-mobile{background:black !important}body.is-theme-unified{background:#1b1a1a}.is-mobile .load-container,.is-theme-unified .load-container{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);z-index:1;visibility:visible;-webkit-transition:visibility 250ms, opacity 250ms linear;-moz-transition:visibility 250ms, opacity 250ms linear;-mz-transition:visibility 250ms, opacity 250ms linear;transition:visibility 250ms, opacity 250ms linear;pointer-events:none}.is-mobile .hide-slide-loader .load-container,.is-theme-unified .hide-slide-loader .load-container{opacity:0;visibility:hidden}.is-mobile .slide-loader,.is-theme-unified .slide-loader{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none;background:none;text-align:center;width:120px;height:80px;top:60%}.is-theme-unified .slide-loader{top:50%}.is-mobile .slide-loader .mobile-loader-dot,.is-theme-unified .slide-loader .mobile-loader-dot{width:30px;height:30px;background-color:white;border-radius:100%;display:inline-block;-webkit-animation:slide-loader 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite both;-moz-animation:slide-loader 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite both;-ms-animation:slide-loader 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite both;animation:slide-loader 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite both}.is-mobile .slide-loader .dot1,.is-theme-unified .slide-loader .dot1{-webkit-animation-delay:-0.2s;-moz-animation-delay:-0.2s;-ms-animation-delay:-0.2s;animation-delay:-0.2s}.is-mobile .slide-loader .dot2,.is-theme-unified .slide-loader .dot2{-webkit-animation-delay:-0.1s;-moz-animation-delay:-0.1s;-ms-animation-delay:-0.1s;animation-delay:-0.1s}@-ms-keyframes slide-loader{0%,80%,100%{-ms-transform:scale(0.6)}40%{-ms-transform:scale(0)}}@-moz-keyframes slide-loader{0%,80%,100%{-moz-transform:scale(0.6)}40%{-moz-transform:scale(0)}}@-webkit-keyframes slide-loader{0%,80%,100%{-webkit-transform:scale(0.6)}40%{-webkit-transform:scale(0)}}@keyframes slide-loader{0%,80%,100%{transform:scale(0.6)}40%{transform:scale(0)}}.mobile-load-title-overlay{display:none}.is-mobile .mobile-load-title-overlay,.is-touchable .mobile-load-title-overlay{display:block;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:999;pointer-events:none}.is-mobile .mobile-load-title-overlay .mobile-load-title,.is-touchable .mobile-load-title-overlay .mobile-load-title{position:relative;height:30%;width:80%;margin:0 auto;line-height:43px;text-align:center;color:#aeb7bd;word-break:break-word}@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (orientation: landscape){.is-mobile .mobile-load-title,.is-touchable .mobile-load-title{font-size:28.8px;-moz-transform:translateY(33%);-ms-transform:translateY(33%);-webkit-transform:translateY(33%);transform:translateY(33%)}}@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait){.is-mobile .slide-loader,.is-touchable .slide-loader{top:55%}.is-mobile .mobile-load-title,.is-touchable .mobile-load-title{font-size:28.8px;-moz-transform:translateY(35%);-ms-transform:translateY(35%);-webkit-transform:translateY(35%);transform:translateY(35%)}}
</style>


</head>
<body style="background: #282828" class="cs-HTML is-theme-unified" role="application">
  <!-- 360 -->
  <script>!function(e){var i=/iPhone/i,o=/iPod/i,n=/iPad/i,t=/(?=.*\bAndroid\b)(?=.*\bMobile\b)/i,d=/Android/i,s=/(?=.*\bAndroid\b)(?=.*\bSD4930UR\b)/i,b=/(?=.*\bAndroid\b)(?=.*\b(?:KFOT|KFTT|KFJWI|KFJWA|KFSOWI|KFTHWI|KFTHWA|KFAPWI|KFAPWA|KFARWI|KFASWI|KFSAWI|KFSAWA)\b)/i,r=/IEMobile/i,h=/(?=.*\bWindows\b)(?=.*\bARM\b)/i,a=/BlackBerry/i,l=/BB10/i,p=/Opera Mini/i,f=/(CriOS|Chrome)(?=.*\bMobile\b)/i,u=/(?=.*\bFirefox\b)(?=.*\bMobile\b)/i,c=new RegExp("(?:Nexus 7|BNTV250|Kindle Fire|Silk|GT-P1000)","i"),w=function(e,i){return e.test(i)},A=function(e){var A=e||navigator.userAgent,v=A.split("[FBAN");if(void 0!==v[1]&&(A=v[0]),this.apple={phone:w(i,A),ipod:w(o,A),tablet:!w(i,A)&&w(n,A),device:w(i,A)||w(o,A)||w(n,A)},this.amazon={phone:w(s,A),tablet:!w(s,A)&&w(b,A),device:w(s,A)||w(b,A)},this.android={phone:w(s,A)||w(t,A),tablet:!w(s,A)&&!w(t,A)&&(w(b,A)||w(d,A)),device:w(s,A)||w(b,A)||w(t,A)||w(d,A)},this.windows={phone:w(r,A),tablet:w(h,A),device:w(r,A)||w(h,A)},this.other={blackberry:w(a,A),blackberry10:w(l,A),opera:w(p,A),firefox:w(u,A),chrome:w(f,A),device:w(a,A)||w(l,A)||w(p,A)||w(u,A)||w(f,A)},this.seven_inch=w(c,A),this.any=this.apple.device||this.android.device||this.windows.device||this.other.device||this.seven_inch,this.phone=this.apple.phone||this.android.phone||this.windows.phone,this.tablet=this.apple.tablet||this.android.tablet||this.windows.tablet,"undefined"==typeof window)return this},v=function(){var e=new A;return e.Class=A,e};"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports&&"undefined"==typeof window?module.exports=A:"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports&&"undefined"!=typeof window?module.exports=v():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("isMobile",[],e.isMobile=v()):e.isMobile=v()}(this);</script>

  <div id="preso"></div>
  <script>
    window.globals = {
      DATA_PATH_BASE: '',
      lmsPresent: false,
      tinCanPresent: false,
      aoSupport: false,
      scale: 'noscale',
      captureRc: false,
      browserSize: 'optimal',
      bgColor: '#282828',
      features: '',
      themeName: 'unified',
      preloaderColor: '#FFFFFF',
      suppressAnalytics: false,
      productChannel: 'stable',
      publishSource: 'storyline',
      aid: 'auth0|5b16890b35b35d50e0b81fef',
      cid: 'd05262b9',
      playerVersion: '3.16.15842.0',


      parseParams: function(qs) {
        if (window.globals.parsedParams != null) {
          return window.globals.parsedParams;
        }
        qs = (qs || window.location.search.substr(1)).split('+').join(' ');
        var params = {},
            tokens,
            re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

        while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
          params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1]).trim()] =
            decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]).trim();
        }
        window.globals.parsedParams = params;
        return params;
      },

    };


    (function() {
      var isPhone = false,
          params = window.globals.parseParams();

      if (params.deviceType != null) { isPhone = params.deviceType === 'phone'; }
      if (params.devicepreview != null) { isPhone = params.phone  == '1'; }

      if (window.globals.themeName !== 'classic') {

        if (params.deviceType != null) {
          window.isMobile.phone = isPhone;
          window.isMobile.tablet = params.deviceType === 'tablet';
          window.isMobile.any = window.isMobile.phone || window.isMobile.tablet;
        }


        if (params.devicepreview != null) {
          window.isMobile.phone = isPhone;
          window.isMobile.tablet = params.devicepreview === '1' && params.phone == null;
          window.isMobile.any = window.isMobile.phone || window.isMobile.tablet;
        }

        if (window.isMobile.any) {
          document.body.classList.add('is-touchable-tablet');
          if (window.isMobile.phone) {
            document.body.classList.add('is-touchable-phone');
          }
        }
      } else if (window.isMobile.any || params.deviceType != null) {
        isPhone = window.isMobile.phone || (params.deviceType === 'phone');

        document.body.classList.add('is-mobile');
        document.body.classList.add(isPhone ? 'is-phone' : 'is-tablet');


        if (window.vInterfaceObject != null && window.vInterfaceObject.isRise) {
          document.body.style.background = 'transparent';
        }
      }
    })();
  </script>
  <script SRC="story_content/user.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></script>
  <div class="slide-loader"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.isMobile.any || window.globals.themeName === 'unified') { var doc = document, loader = doc.body.querySelector('.slide-loader'); [ 1, 2, 3 ].forEach(function(n) { var d = doc.createElement('div'); d.style.backgroundColor = window.globals.preloaderColor; d.classList.add('mobile-loader-dot'); d.classList.add('dot' + n); loader.appendChild(d);
      });
    }
  </script>

  <div class="mobile-load-title-overlay">
    <div class="mobile-load-title">Untitled1</div>
  </div>
  <script>

    if (window.autoSpider && window.vInterfaceObject) {
      document.querySelector('.mobile-load-title-overlay').style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>

  <div class="mobile-chrome-warning">
    <div class="mobile-chrome-warning-btn">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0px" y="0px" width="107px" height="78px" viewBox="0 0 107 78">

          <g id="mobile-chrome-warning-arrow">
            <path fill="white" stroke="none" d="
            M 24.1 31.4
            L 12.05 15.85 0 31.4 8.3 31.4 8.3 54 15.25 54 15.25 31.4 24.1 31.4 Z"/>
          </g>

          <path id="mobile-chrome-warning-hand" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
          M 37.55 16.1
          Q 36.3 14.8 36.3 13.1 36.3 11.45 37.55 10.15 38.85 8.9 40.55 8.9 42.2 8.9 43.5 10.15
          L 46.75 13.375 46.75 13.35
          Q 45.5 12.05 45.5 10.35 45.5 8.7 46.75 7.4 48.05 6.15 49.75 6.15 51.4 6.15 52.7 7.4
          L 57 11.65
          Q 56.05 10.4828125 56.05 9 56.05 7.3 57.3 6 58.6 4.8 60.3 4.8 62 4.8 63.3 6
          L 74.3 17
          Q 76.3 19.05 77.5 21.55 78.75 24.05 79.1 26.9 79.4 29.7 80.65 32.25 81.85 34.75 83.85 36.75
          L 85.6 38.5 69.5 54.6
          Q 68.25 53.35 66.5 52.1 64.75 50.8 62.85 49.85 60.95 48.85 59.25 48.5
          L 32 42.5
          Q 31.15 42.3 30.45 41.8 29.1 40.8 28.85 39.3 28.6 37.85 29.35 36.55 30.05 35.25 31.65 34.7
          L 31.9 34.65
          Q 32.55 34.45 33.25 34.45
          L 44.3 34.9 17.65 8.2
          Q 16.4 6.9 16.4 5.2 16.4 3.55 17.65 2.25 18.95 1 20.65 1 22.3 1 23.6 2.25
          L 37.55 16.1 39.2 17.75
          M 58.95 13.65
          L 58.075 12.775 57.3 12
          Q 57.140234375 11.833984375 57 11.65
          L 58.075 12.775
          M 46.75 13.375
          L 48.4 15"/>

        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="mobile-chrome-warning-bubble">
        Drag up for fullscreen
      </div>
  </div>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="html5/lib/stylesheets/main.min.css" data-noprefix />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="html5/data/css/output.min.css" data-noprefix />
  <script data-main="app/scripts/init.generated" src="html5/lib/scripts/app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You say that the URL is correct, yet ta 404 clearly implies otherwise. Check the URL you're calling is what you assume it is in the network tab of the console. You may need to make the path relative to the root of the site instead of the current page etc...

Comment: The url is correct , I checked it in the browser (copy paste, full path)

Comment: When you put that URL in your JS have you included the `http://`? Are you making a cross-domain request?

Comment: yes, I have put http://

Comment: In which case there's not enough information to help you. With what you've stated here the code should be working.